# How to spot Andromeda in a 130mm telescope?

Tags: telescope, amateur-observing, star-gazing

I have no problem to spot orion nebula, I mean the blue splash caused by the gas on my 130mm reflector telescope but I can’t see the same on Andromeda, what I am missing?

Comment: Let me ask you an off-topic question.  How long have you been interested in astronomy?  Your question is interesting for beginners, it seems to me.  I will support.

Comment: Are you saying you cannot see it at all?? The Andromeda Galaxy is visible with the naked eye from a dark sight and with binoculars from a light polluted sight. How dark is your sky? If you cannot see it in a 130 mm scope, you are either overlooking it (it's fainter than you exoect) or you are not pointing at it.

Comment: Can you see the stars labeled μ and ν on [this map](https://www.iau.org/public/images/detail/and/)?

Comment: Yes, I am a beginner. I can see planets pretty good. I will check about μ and ν, my sky is no clear these days. As I stated, I can see starts and I am pretty sure I am pointing to the right direction. What I was expecting to see is the "gas dust" like that circles the center.